pivot filter with no data for all filter categories
I need help/idea on this problem.   I have a raw data under monthly sales of 20 different products from four regions where each region consists of 10 different areas each. sometimes there will be no sales in particular area(s) or entire region(s) in a particular month. The issue is when i make pivot table for the data, filtered table would not show any data  where no sales. i want to show nil/zero sales to area(s) and/or region(s) where no sales have been recorded.
How to make it?
Thanks in advance..
I tried with making 0 sales to all areas. But it takes time to enter data to all the areas.

Create a Pivot table with both Rows and Columns, this way combinations of areas/regions that have nil sales will be visible.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
